# Is it possible to use the laser barcode scanner on a handheld terminal that runs android using apache cordova?

Tags: cordova, handhelddevice

Is it possible to use laser barcode scanner of a handheld terminal that has android os with using apache cordova ?

Here is a link of motorola android handheld terminals: http://www.ptsmobile.com/cat/mc40-barcode-terminals.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Motorola (Zebra) devices, you can use the datawedge plugin https://github.com/BlueFletch/motorola-datawedge-cordova-plugin.git

Once you've added the plugin to your project, you have to add code to your app to initialise the barcode reader and then you will have to run the Datawedge application to add a profile for your cordova application.

With that you'll be able to use the super-fast native reader of Motorola devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what i was looking for.